# how do I access my svn repository remotely?

Tags: windows, svn, version-control

I have a domain. And I have a dedicated windows server. It has svn installed and I created a `svn` repository. How do I setup usernames and passwords to access it. And how do I access it remotely without having to go through remote desktop? My repository is located remotely on my server at `c:\svn`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2548168/how-to-access-subversion-server-remotely

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not exactly sure how you have structure up the directory in your svn server but the file path use to look something like this.
svn\repository\projectname\conf

in this folder you will find a file named passwd open it in a text editor and input the username you want to your svn like this.
username = password

About the remote access it should be ready from the beginning. Using the hierarchy i showed before the link should looks like this.

svn://domain.topdomain/projectname

Comment: hey what if say my url is http://mydomain.com and like I said in the beginning I had my repository in c:\svn how would I get to it over the internet after I created my username?

Comment: if the data for the repository is just put in the svn folder and not in it's own folder it should be found under svn://mydomain.com

Answer (score 0):

For remote access you have to enable any of supported network protocol - http:// over Apache or svn:// with svnserve